# Spring parent child transaction management

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

If my child is registered as a spring bean and propagation behavior is annotated to `REQUIRED` at class level and if i am calling the child's method which is in parent then will the parent method be part of spring transaction management ?

For example,

```
class Parent {
  public void method() {
    System.out.println("Parent");
  }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
class Child extends Parent {

}
```

If yes, can we say that the parent is also a spring bean ?

Comment: No it won't. Also `Parent` isn't a bean because `Child` is a bean.

Comment: When i update the parent method with REQUIRED annotation, we are observing that it works.

Comment: Correct as it should. But that still doesn't make the  `Parent` a seperate bean. If you define a `Child` as bean that is the bean you won't get 2 beans.

Comment: Ok. Can you explain how the method was eligible for transaction management when the annotation was added ?

Comment: `@Transactional` only operates on methods defined in the same class. Not for methods of the super or child class.

Comment: Exactly. so, when i added the annotation @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) inside the parent method, how did it work ?

Comment: As stated because it was on the parent it works. Not when you place it on the child class. The latter would only apply to methods defined in the child class itslef NOT on methods defined in the parent class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189076/discussion-between-adithya-and-m-deinum).